# Erro em usar função glob com wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Estou tentando recuperar imagens de uma pasta com a função nativa do php `glob`, só que está retornando um *array* vazio.
Eu estou passando o caminho completo da pasta pra função.

Segue código:

```
$pasta = get_template_directory_uri() . '/img/projetos/' . get_post_meta($post->ID, 'projeto', true) .'/';              
$imagens = glob("$pasta{*jpg,*png}", GLOB_BRACE) or die ("Erro ao acessar $pasta");
```

Comment: Por favor, informe o erro que está acontecendo.

Comment: Qual é o valor da concatenação "$pasta{*jpg,*png}"? Consegue imprimir e postar aqui? Essa notação que você está tentando usar eu só conheço no shell, em regex eu faria algo como (jpg|png).

Answer (score 2):

Você está passando uma URL ([`get_template_directory_uri`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory_uri)) mas o [`glob`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.glob.php) está esperando um Path/Caminho ([`get_template_directory`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory)).

O seguinte código funciona:

```
$pasta = get_template_directory() . '/img/' ;              
$imagens = glob("$pasta{*jpg,*png}", GLOB_BRACE) or die ("Erro ao acessar $pasta");
echo '<pre>' . print_r( $imagens, true ) . '</pre>';
```

E, para converter o Caminho em URL, seria um simples:

```
$path = get_template_directory();
$url = get_template_directory_uri();
foreach( $imagens as $img )
    echo str_replace( $path, $url, $img ) . '<br />';
```

Answer (score 0):

Antes de mais nada, verifique se seu path $pasta é válido "precisa terminar com **/**"

Depois, use isso:

```
$a = glob($pasta.'*.{jpg,png}',GLOB_BRACE);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($a);
```